# Customizing layered navigation by Categories in Magento

Tags: magento, layered-navigation

I'm using layered navigation for a category in my **magento** store. 
But some products have multiple categories.

Say I have a category *she*. Again I have some other categories like *t-shirt*, *cosmetics* etc. A *t-shirt* may have both *t-shirt* and *she* categories. Again a *cosmetics* item may have both *she* and *cosmetics* categories. So when I'm displaying *she* category page, I want to show *t-shirt* and *cosmetics* categories in layered navigation. When user clicking on one of those categories (say *t-shirt*) it will show all the *t-shirt* which also fall in *she* category.

How to do this?

**EDIT**: Here one thing I need to make clear. she, t-shirt, cosmetics all are independent categories. none are sub category of another.

Comment: this would work if you have one and the same product in category and sub-category. If you want to list all sub-categories for the category you should add your own block with this functionality.

Comment: @Pavel Novitsky, If all the categories are independent will the appear on layered navigation?

Comment: no, it works only for sub-categories and products

Answer (score 0):

This is a Magento feature, if it doesn't work it's because you have deactivate something in your code that break this functionnality.

This should work as a normal filter with name = 'cat' and value = category ids.

Best Regards,

Comment: When all the categories are independent will they appear on layered navigation? I see just subcategories are listed on layered navigation.